# How to filter concated columns with LIKE using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a users table with a `first_name` and a `last_name` column. I am trying to create a SQLAlchemy query that will perform a like on a concatanation of the two columns, IE full name. Here is an example

`first_name: Bob`

`last_name: Smith`

`query = "bob smi"`

I am looking for query something like:

`session.query(Person).filter((Person.firstName + " " + Person.lastName).like(query+'%')`

Such that a search for `bob smi` will return `bob smith`

Thanks!

Comment: It should work the way you wrote it if you add a space between `firstName` and `lastName`

Answer (score 10):

you were close, what you need is to construct the following query in sqla:

```
root@localhost [inDB]> SELECT * FROM Person;
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|         1 | Bob        | Smith     |
|         2 | John       | Smith     |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [inDB]> SELECT * FROM Person WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE 'Bob Sm%';
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| person_id | first_name | last_name |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|         1 | Bob        | Smith     |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

then it will become clear that you need a filter with concat() function:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
res = session.query(Person).filter(func.concat(Person.first_name, ' ', Person.last_name).like('Bob Sm%')).all()
len(res)  # is 1
res, = res
print res.first_name, res.last_name  # 'Bob Smith'
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work across all database types as the `+` operator is translated the SQL `||` operator when used between strings:

```
session.query(Person).filter((
        Person.first_name + ' ' + Person.last_name
    ).like('{0}%'.format(query))
)
```